# Error when setting DATABASE_NAME when creating a external data source

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm facing a problem with cross database calls now when migrating from SQL Server to Azure. I have a SP called '**sp_GetProfileDescription**' on both **db1** and **db2**. On **db1**, '**sp_GetProfileDescription**' is called and passing some parameters to it. 
Then I select a name for **db2** dynamically(it's different depending on what profile is calling) and then call **db2**'s '**sp_GetProfileDescription**' and pass along the parameters to it.

In SQL Server I did like this:

```
@ConId int, 
@ProfileId varchar(100),
@LanguageCode char(2) = NULL,
@Description nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT
...
...
...

DECLARE @dbName varchar(100) = NULL

SELECT 
    @dbName = [providerDatabaseName] 
FROM
    [Con] WHERE id = @ConId 

IF @dbName IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN               

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) =  N'USE [' + @dbName +']; EXEC sp_GetProfileDescription @ProfileId, @LanguageCode, @Description OUTPUT'                

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ProfileId varchar(100), @LanguageCode char(2), @Description nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @ProfileId, @LanguageCode, @Description OUTPUT   

END
```

No when migrating to Azure I'm doing like below but I'm getting an error saying "*Incorrect syntax near '@dbName*'." and it's referring to "**DATABASE_NAME= @dbName**" where I create the data source.

```
@ConId int, 
@ProfileId varchar(100),
@LanguageCode char(2) = NULL,
@Description nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT
...
...
...

DECLARE @dbName varchar(100) = NULL

SELECT 
    @dbName = [providerDatabaseName] 
FROM
    [Con] WHERE id = @ConId 

IF @dbName IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN               

    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ProviderDB
    WITH
    (
        TYPE=RDBMS,
        LOCATION='mydomain.database.windows.net',
        DATABASE_NAME= @dbName,
        CREDENTIAL= dbadmin
    );

    EXEC sp_execute_remote @data_source_name  = N'ProviderDB', 
    @stmt = N'EXEC sp_GetProfileDescription @ProfileId, @LanguageCode, @Description OUTPUT', 
    @params = N'@ProfileId varchar(100), @LanguageCode char(2), @Description nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT',
    @ProfileId=@ProfileId, @LanguageCode=@LanguageCode, @Description=@Description OUTPUT;

END
```

The problem seem to be that I'm using a vaiable when setting **DATABASE_NAME**. If I hardcode it it seem to work but I need to have it set dynamically. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ProviderDB
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='mydomain.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME= @dbName,
    CREDENTIAL= dbadmin
);
```

With (or something very similar)

```
EXEC('CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ProviderDB WITH( TYPE=RDBMS, LOCATION='mydomain.database.windows.net', DATABASE_NAME=' + @dbName + ', CREDENTIAL= dbadmin);')
```

You ought to be careful with SQL injection in that approach, as it leaves you open to a pretty straightforward attack.